# How to tell JavaFX WebView to ignore 'use strict' directive?

Tags: java, javafx, webkit, mozilla, pdf.js

I am trying to integrate the mozilla viewer in a JavaFx WebView by using the following code:

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;


    public class TestStrict extends Application {

      @Override
      public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        WebView webView = new WebView();

        String url = TestStrict.class.getClassLoader().getResource("pdfjs-1.1.366-dist/web/viewer.html").toExternalForm();
        webView.getEngine().load(url);

        Scene scene = new Scene(webView);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.setWidth(800);
        primaryStage.setHeight(600);

        primaryStage.show();

      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
      }

    }
```

The pdfjs-1.1.366-dist folder is downloaded from [pdfjs GitHub](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/releases/download/v1.1.366/pdfjs-1.1.366-dist.zip)

I also changed the `viewer.html` just to add firebug-lite inside:

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/1.2/firebug-lite-compressed.js'></script>
```

Now when I run the application I get the viewer frame but without the default pdf loaded and the following error is inside firebug console:

> "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'globalScope.PDFJS') (pdf.worker.js,103)"

I removed all the 'use strict' directives in the javascript files and everything is working fine.

I don't know if this is a bug in JavaFX or internal WebKit but it happens with version 1.8.0_60.

**So is there any way that I can disable strict mode since there will be other web pages that will be loaded where I can't control the scripts and remove 'use strict' directives?**