# Dynamic HTML with Javascript in JavaFX Webview

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, webview, javafx

I will try to ask my Question as precise as I can. At the moment I cannot post any example Code as I'm not allowed to post code of my work. In my next free time I will lookup that I will code some example to be more precise.

Here is my Question:

I'm developing some project where I built some HTML and Javascript code dynamically with Java and load it into a Webview of JavaFX. The Html has to be generated dynamically because there are lots of Information in it that come up from a central database. Then I try to run it via a ChangeListener that is set on LoadWorker for the WebEngine of the Webview to ensure that the Webpage is loaded. The page is loaded correctly but when I try to use some javascript function the Application crashes.

The whole thing is working with a local written html document. In the Html are lots of Javascript-Libraries like Jquery and others. But my project crashes because the libraries and its functions cannot be used. I think that the http-Request of loading a local written html sets up these javascript when the webpage is loaded.

Am I correct with this? 
And is there anything I can fix this Problem with dynamic generated htmls loaded in a Webview.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You will need to supply an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get assistance (make sure it is absolutely minimal to replicating the issue).  You should be able to generate such an mcve without divulging any potentially confidential work related information.  Full detail of your operating environment (OS/Java version) is also helpful.  Also detail what you mean by crash (e.g. does the JVM exit? are there any error codes displayed?) and provide any error traces generated.

Comment: On first thought, I thought the issue may have been related to this known issue with Java 8: [JDK-8087652 WebView crashes on calling webEngine.load(url) in a webEngine.locationProperty() ChangeListener](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8087652).  However, on re-reading the question, perhaps not.

Comment: To me it looks like a bit like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33258381/how-to-tell-javafx-webview-to-ignore-use-strict-directive. Make sure that you have logging on the WebPage enabled. Furthermore there were some fixes with the update 1.8.0_60 which had some effects on the execution of JavaScript in the `WebEngine`.